# Как в ubuntu 16.04 разрешить sftp и ssh?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp

Настроил sftp, через PuTTy хотел подключиться к серверу через ssh, пишет "This service allows sftp connections only." Как разрешить ssh connection?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите вывод команды `id пользователь-под-которым-пытаетесь-подключиться`

Comment: весь интернет перерыл нигде не нашел ничего. Есть вариант установить proftpd и там настроить fstp отдельно от ssh

Comment: да у вас всё отлично работает. только ваш пользователь, видимо, входит в группу sftpgroup и потому на него накладываются ограничение в виде chrootdirectory, которое видно на приведённой вами картинке. уберите это ограничение или уберите пользователя из группы sftpgroup — и будет этот ваш пользователь отлично подключаться и по ssh и по sftp.

Comment: Выкладывать текстовый конфиг в виде картинки - не самая лучшая идея. Перевыложи в виде текста. И лучше сразу весь, а не часть.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, Короче дело вот в чем, один пользователь с правами судо будет заходить только через ssh, а группа sftpgroup только через sftp, т.е. создаем еще одного пользователя для sftp и добавляем его в группу sftpgroup. Также меняем у sftp-полльзователя домашнюю папку на /var/www/html например

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно установить (если он еще не установлен) и включить сервер `sshd`. Для установки сервера нужно установить пакет `opennssh-server`

```
sudo apt-get install opennssh-server
```

или более общий пакет ssh, который установит `openssh-server`, как зависимый пакет:

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

Запуск SSH-сервера, как и всех остальных серверов в Ubuntu, осуществляется при помощи команды `service`:

```
sudo service ssh start
```

Перезапуск сервера выполняется посредством команды `restart`:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Перечитать измененный конфигурационный файл сервера, не останавливая сервер,
можно при помощи команды

```
sudo service ssh reload
```

Остановка сервера осуществляется при помощи команды `stop`:

```
sudo service ssh stop
```

Comment: через файлзиллу подключаюсь к серверу по sftp все норм

Comment: sshd работает? его видно в процессах ps aux | grep sshd?

Comment: да видно, все работает

Comment: Из под какого пользователя подключаетесь? Ели не сложно, дополните вопрос содержимым /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: скрин скинул в теме

Answer (score 1):

Дело вот в чем, один пользователь с правами **sudo** будет заходить только через ssh, а группа `sftpgroup` только через sftp, т.е. создаем еще одного пользователя для sftp и добавляем его в группу `sftpgroup`. Также меняем у sftp-пользователя домашнюю папку на `/var/www/html` например